# ¿Es válido editar para corregir errores profundos?

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Tengo un problema con cierto tipo de ediciones que corrigen potenciales errores profundos, ilustradas por ésta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/241195.

Entiendo que una edición mejora la comprensión de un texto al arreglar su redacción, ortografía, ordenamiento y formato.

Una edición profunda, por otra parte, cambia el *significado* del texto al modificar el código de un programa o el sentido de lo que se escribe.

**Resumen**

La edición mencionada es larga; tome sólo esta línea como ejemplo:

Original:

> ?!     -> conocido como Negated lookahead en inglés

Correción:

> (?!  ) -> conocido como Negated lookahead en inglés

Justificación dada por el editor:

> ?! no tiene el mismo significado que (?! ... ) Un lookahead negativo
> se define con paréntesis. Por más que parezca bueno acortarlo para
> explicar, resulta técnicamente incorrecto. Está bien en todo el resto
> de la respuesta excepto donde modifiqué ... ++ Hay lookbehind en
> JavaScript

No soy experto en el tema puntual (expresiones regulares, JS); no puedo decir quién está en lo correcto, pero no es el punto aquí. El problema es ¿Es válido corregir vía edición un error (real o percibido) en el texto de otra persona?

En lo personal, habría optado por agregar un comentario a la respuesta en cuestión, o bien ofrecer mi propia respuesta señalando los problemas de la otra.

El problema con correcciones profundas a textos de terceros es que uno puede estar equivocado después de todo y dejar las cosas peor de lo que estaban.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primero que nada, estamos hablando de una respuesta, que es un mundo muy distinto al de las preguntas. En mi opinión es totalmente válido, cuando se usa de forma positiva:

- Por que el sistema lo permite
- Por que permite mejorar la calidad de un respuesta
- Por que puede corregir eventuales errores tipográficos
- Por que permite añadir información que podría ser relevante
- Por que el sistema respeta la potestad del autor sobre la pregunta, es el mismo el que puede eventualmente rechazar la edición.
- Por que queda registro completo de los cambios
- Por que los cambios y el contenido en general es auditado todo el tiempo por la comunidad

Un paso intermedio, sería comentarle al autor, y señalarle los cambios que son pertinentes hacerle, pero en mi opinión eso termina siendo más burocrático, difícil y no necesariamente se consiga los resultados esperados. Creo que la filosofía de "pedir perdón antes que permiso", funciona bien en este tema.

Por supuesto, hay casos dónde se deberían rechazar estas ediciones:

- Cuando se cambia el sentido de la respuesta, "la solución es X" pasa a ser "la solución es Y"
- No mejora significativamente la calidad de la respuesta
- Es vandalismo

Lo de:

> El problema con correcciones profundas a textos de terceros es que uno
> puede estar equivocado después de todo y dejar las cosas peor de lo
> que estaban.

Es un buen punto, pero es algo que ciertamente la persona técnicamente honesta, no puede saber de antemano. Si hace la edición, es por que considera que es pertinente, entonces ¿se debería cuidar de hacerla por el riesgo de eventualmente equivocarse? en mi opinión no.

En el sentido de lo que comento, el ejemplo que has dado es muy bueno, es cierto que es una edición importante, pero los cambios y aclaraciones en general, en mi opinión, mejoran significativamente la respuesta sin cambiar el sentido de la misma.

Por otro lado, tu pregunta, tiene implícita una cuestión de fondo muy interesante ¿Cuándo mejorar una respuesta ya realizada y cuándo corresponde hacer una nueva? pero eso da material para una nueva pregunta (si todavía no fue realizada aún)

Comment: +1 comparto plenamente tu opinion...

Answer (score 5):

Yo soy quien propuso esa edición. Es cierto que fue una edición más que significativa, creo que fue en la que más modifiqué hasta ahora. La hice a consciencia, conociendo sobre el tema, e intentando mejorar la calidad de la respuesta. El autor decidió rechazarla, así que ahí muere como sugerencia, pero no quita que podamos discutir sobre lo que estás preguntando.

Si bien creo que estás preguntando sobre ediciones que cambien el significado de una respuesta, creo que interpretaste mal la edición. La verdad es que no puedo responder a lo que yo interpreto de una pregunta que hable de "*corregir errores profundos*", cuando el ejemplo que das no está corrigiendo ningún error. Sé perfectamente que se puede interpretar como eso, pero no lo es. Perdón si desvío el tema, respondería otra cosa si fuese otro el ejemplo, quizás más cercano a [lo que respondió Patricio Moracho](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4917/193460).

Definiste:

> Una edición profunda, por otra parte, cambia el significado del texto al modificar el código de un programa o el sentido de lo que se escribe

Y mi sugerencia de edición no cambia el significado del texto, no modifica el código, ni el sentido de lo que se describe. Creo que tomaste lo que puse en el resumen de la edición "*resulta técnicamente incorrecto*" para asumir que estaba corrigiendo un error (-sí, ahora veo que da lugar a interpretarlo mal), pero es análogo a si en [una de tus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/398371/193460) no usaras paréntesis describiendo a `funcion(n)`:

> - *Idempotentes.* Es decir, `funcion n` siempre retornara el mismo valor para un `n` dado.

y lo corrigiera a como en realidad lo publicaste:

> - *Idempotentes.* Es decir, `funcion(n)` siempre retornara el mismo valor para un `n` dado.

---

De hecho, mientras editaba, no me parecía muy bien una pequeña parte de la respuesta porque está mezclando 2 técnicas diferentes en 1 (describe bien la *técnica de descarte* pero en realidad presenta un código que corresponde a un *reseteo del inicio de la coincidencia*). Fijate que no toqué esa parte y lo publiqué como una nueva respuesta a la misma pregunta, sin mencionar en absoluto que me parecía mal, sólo dando la información objetiva, e iniciando mi respuesta con "*La respuesta de Federico Piazza es excelente, lean esa primero. -Yo quiero complementarla*". Esta fue la respuesta que publiqué:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/404876/193460

---

Hay mucho para mencionar de los cambios. Intenté buscar la forma de reducir y contextualizar, pero no pude. Disculpen, pero no se me ocurre otra cosa más que ir explicando las correcciones una por una, empezando por la que mencionás en la pregunta:

**1. Lookahead descrito como `?!` --- modifiqué por `(?!  )`**

El autor usa lookaheads negativos varias veces como `hola(?!chau)`. Simplemente que al principio pone una pequeña **descripción** como `?!`. Los menciona de esta forma porque así venían de la pregunta. No está equivocado y no lo utiliza mal en ningún lado.

Es importante que sepas primero que `?!` no existe. No es una estructura sintáctica. Es exclusivamente una forma que se usó para mencionar a `(?!`..`)` de forma abreviada. Los paréntesis son parte del lookahead y el lookahead no existe sin esos paréntesis.

```js
console.log('Probando (?!)  ::: ', /(?!)/);

console.log('Mostrando que no existe ?!');
/?!/;
```

Mi modificación fue sobre una descripción, no sobre el código. Y al cambiarlo a `(?!  )` no estoy corrigiendo un error, sino que estoy poniendo lo mismo que usó el autor en toda su publicación de forma completa. Te aseguro que el autor sabe esto y que es lo mismo que está diciendo.

¿Por qué opté por esta modificación? No fue porque piense que no esté claro, tampoco creo que lo esté explicando mal, sino que sé por experiencia que muchos desarrolladores que recién comienzan con regex tienden a confundirse pensando que `?!` es el lookahead y los paréntesis lo agrupan (como sucede con cualquier otro paréntesis que no esté seguido por `?`), un concepto que es importante aclarar desde el inicio. Mi intención es que no preste lugar a confusión sobre lo que está explicando la respuesta.

Como mencioné antes, sería lo mismo que modificar `def funcion n` por `def funcion(n)` en una publicación que se usó bien en todo el código pero quedó explicada en 1 solo lugar sin los paréntesis.

**2. Hay lookbehind en JavaScript**

Esta sí fue una modificación que cambia el significado de la respuesta. Sin embargo, no es una corrección sino una actualización.

En el 2016, cuando se publicó la respuesta, era cierto que no existían lookbehinds en JavaScript. En 2017 se incluyeron en Chrome y a partir de ahí en todos los grandes salvo Safari (e IE). Citando una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142631/193460) a otra pregunta:

> Las inspecciones hacia atrás (*lookbehinds*) fueron implementadas recientemente en Chrome 62+ (21/8/17) ([issue 4545](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545&desc=2#c20)) y en Opera 49+ ([status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5668726032564224)). Podrías utilizarla en estos navegadores, aunque todavía es demasiado temprano como para pensar en usarlos en una solución que sea compatible con la mayoría de los navegadores.

- dice "recientemente" y "demasiado temprano" pero porque se publicó en 2018.

Lo que estaba haciendo era poner al día a esa respuesta, reflejando las actualizaciones que ocurrieron hace 3 años y que ya están hoy en un 78% de los navegadores utilizados. Además, lo incluí de la forma más sutil que se me ocurrió, para que no impacte en lo que se estaba describiendo.

Sugerí modificar:

> Es importante mencionar que los ***lookbehind* no estan soportados por Javascript**.

Por:

> Es importante mencionar que los ***lookbehind* no están soportados por Javascript en todos los navegadores** ([ver compatibilidad](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)).

En paralelo, esta actualización no modifica ni invalida en **ningún** aspecto lo que se está respondiendo. El hecho de que los lookbehinds sean de largo fijo hace que, aún cuando existan en JavaScript, sigan siendo inutilizables para el problema planteado en la pregunta, y no son una alternativa viable para ninguno de los métodos que se están presentando en esa respuesta. Únicamente [.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) permite lookbehinds de largo variable, y podrían usarse para lograr responder lo que se pregunta, pero sería un regex tan ineficiente que también sería inválido en algún aspecto.

O sea, no estoy cambiando el significado, ni estoy haciendo que sea incoherente al actualizar algo que entre en conflicto con el resto de la respuesta. Simplemente estoy poniendo la información al día para evitar que un lector no informado se lleve la idea de que no existen en JavaScript.

**3. "No coincidir" -- modificado a "coincidir con algo que no sea..."**

El autor había escrito:

> Del mismo modo, una clase se puede negar, como mencionaste usando `^` al principio... por lo que `[^aeiou]` en este caso *no* va a hacer matching con las vocales.

y sugerí modificar por:

> Del mismo modo, una clase se puede negar, como mencionaste usando `^` al principio... por lo que `[^aeiou]` en este caso va a hacer matching con un caracter que *no* sea una vocal sin tilde.

En este caso no estoy modificando el significado, sino la forma de explicarlo. Me parece que decir que "*no va a coincidir*" puede dar una idea falsa a un lector. Una clase de caracteres **siempre** coincide con caracteres. Además, opté por utilizar el texto "*una vocal sin tilde*" -que no es como yo lo describiría- porque así es como el autor venía describiendo a `[aeiou]` (el caso opuesto).

De nuevo, no tiene que ver con el contenido sino con la información que se puede llevar un lector no informado.

**4. PCRE no está solo en PHP**

Sugerí modificar:

> PCRE (Expresiones Regulares Compatibles con Perl, soportadas por PHP)

Por:

> PCRE (Expresiones Regulares Compatibles con Perl, soportadas por PHP, R, Delphi y otros)

agregando más información en algo que es totalmente accesorio a lo que se publicó. Me pareció importante poner de esta manera que PCRE no es exclusivo a PHP. De hecho, no incluí a Perl, C, C++ y Python porque si bien se puede usar PCRE, no es la librería estándar. Tampoco puse otros lenguajes/herramientas como Julia, Nginx, Apache (.htaccess) o Notepad++ por un tema de relevancia.

**5. descartar patrones -- modificado a descartar coincidencias**

Sugerí modificar:

> la expresión de arriba `".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+)` va a descartar todos los patrones que contengan skip/fail

Por:

> la expresión de arriba `".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+)` va a descartar todas las coincidencias de lo que esté antes de skip y fail (`".*?"`)

En este caso es un tema de redacción exclusivamente. Lo que se descarta no son patrones sino coincidencias. No pasa por un tema conceptual, sino de las palabras utilizadas para describirlo. Me pareció que de esta forma quedaba mejor explicado.

**6. El resto...**

son meramente correcciones ortográficas y de formato.

---

---

En definitiva, entiendo que cuando hablamos de expresiones regulares resulte complejo discernir cuándo se está modificando el contenido y cuándo no. También soy consciente de que el comentario que puse resumiendo la modificación daba lugar a pensar lo contrario si iba a alguien que no esté familiarizado con esto. Sin embargo, creo que si vamos a hablar de "*corregir errores profundos*" también tenemos que tener en cuenta que puede haber lugar para errores de interpretación de lo que se está sugiriendo editar.

La idea es siempre mejorar la calidad de las publicaciones. Y en este caso estoy convencido de que lo hacía. Como mencioné antes, creo que hay lugar para hablar de otro tipo de publicaciones, pero busquemos un ejemplo concreto que esté corrigiendo errores profundos primero.

Comment: Es excelente la sugerencia que hiciste y una pena que el autor de la respuesta no la aceptara pues la hacía mejor.

Comment: Excelente explicación. Por favor, siente libre de modificar de ese modo cualquiera de mis respuestas :-)

Comment: Hola @pollo, soy el autor de la pregunta que editaste. Rechace la revision (precipitadamente por lo que veo), al ver que habian variado muchas cosas y cuando vi lo de los lookbehind en javascript, que por este post en meta me entero de que empezaron a ser soportados en algunos navegadores, pense que era una actualizacion incorrecta. No tengo reputacion suficienta para ver las herramientas de moderador, pero si abris nuevamente la edicion la apruebo con gusto. Te pido disculpas por rechazarla precipitadamente.

Comment: No responde a mi pregunta. Si cambio el ejemplo que dí por otro, tu respuesta pierde toda validez.

Comment: Buenísimo @Federico. Ahí envié de nuevo. Nada que disculpar hombre!! Toda sugerencia es eso: una sugerencia... Pero está bueno que ahora entiendo el motivo del rechazo :-)  y genial que quieras que incluya la edición. Gracias!

Comment: @CandidMoe claro, es lo que menciono varias veces en la respuesta. Sin embargo, convengamos que cuando uno incluye un ejemplo de la misma forma que lo incluiste, comienza a ser parte importante de la pregunta. Y creo que sí responde en el sentido de decir "estás interpretando mal la sugerencia de edición"... Como sabrás, cada uno puede tener una idea diferente de lo que significa "*corregir errores profundos*", cada cual tendrá su concepto de "profundo" y creo que un ejemplo es el que termina de aclarar a qué te estás refiriendo.

Comment: Como he dicho, tus correcciones son técnicamente correctas hasta donde puedo apreciar. Eso no está en discusión. Lo que discuto es que se puedan hacer esas correcciones. Si eso es permisible, podría pasarme el día corrigiendo respuestas que no contestan la pregunta, que son incompletas, imprecisas o con código con errores de sintaxis y/o lógica. Yo no hago eso; educamente digo "Revisa tu respuesta".

Comment: @CandidMoe lo entendí en todo momento, pero te pediría un ejemplo para ver de qué tipo de ediciones hablamos.

Comment: @Pollo. "saramago".

Comment: @CandidMoe La verdad no recuerdo una edición en esa publicación. Y si hablás de una hipotética edición, tampoco se me ocurre qué error profundo se corregiría, solo era algo incompleta. Pero en todo caso podrías editar tu pregunta explicando.. Tema aparte, me da la sensación de que te tomaste mal esta respuesta y te digo lo mismo que me comentaste: no es algo personal. Estoy respondiendo objetivamente a lo que se hizo en la edición. Realmente, cero problemas y me vas a seguir teniendo como votante frecuente de tus respuestas... No sé qué más decirte, ¿cerramos el tema acá y pasamos a otra cosa?